# EDSAC - 17-bit and 35-bit integers

Tags: integer, bit, obsolete

I'm trying to write a program for [EDSAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EDSAC) and am stuck on understanding the short and long integer stuff - sometimes I enter something and get a zero, and at others I get a one.

So, for example:

If I enter `P0F`, 0 is stored.

If I enter `P0D`, 1 is stored.

If I enter `P1F`, 2 is stored

If I enter `P2D`, 3 is stored.

`F` means use a 17-bit integer, and `D` means a full length 35-bit integer.

Can someone explain why P0F and P0D don't have the same integer value, just a different bit length?

Comment: For folks who have too much time on their hands: [the EDSAC Simulator](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~edsac/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am currently doing an assignment on EDSAC, and from messing around trying to work out how to store constants, I have found that it appears to work as follows:

- `PNF` where `N` is an integer stores the value 2N
- `PND` where `N` is an integer stores the value 2N+1

Comment: In the question `P2D` stored 3. This suggests that it would store 5?